# .htaccess in hosting Windows

Tags: .htaccess, iis, hosting

I recently bought a web hosting with windows (IIS).
The site that I have to transfer to hosting uses the following .htaccess file

```
    Options -Indexes

# Various rewrite rules.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico

  RewriteRule ^(.*)(\.)(.*)$ index.php?url=$1.$3 [L,QSA]
  RewriteRule ^ajax$ _res/ajax.php [QSA]
  #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?t=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

On the new server that uses IIS it does not work, how do I solve it?

Comment: Some can be translated, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-applications-on-iis/translate-htaccess-content-to-iis-webconfig while others might not. You still need to learn IIS configuration system and manually configure it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your website web.config file add the `rewrite` section under the `system.webServer` section as shown below:

```
<system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*)(\.)(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{URL}" pattern="^/favicon.ico$" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?url={R:1}.{R:3}" appendQueryString="true" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Rule 2">
                    <match url="^ajax$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="_res/ajax.php" appendQueryString="true" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Rule 3" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?t={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
```

Also, ensure that you have `Url Rewrite` IIS extension installed on your server.